Sending of the message failed - Insufficient system storage
I have Debian 11 with Postfix and dovecot. My mail was working fine until yesterday but today Im having the following error:
Sending of the message failed.
The message was not sent due to exceeding the allowed number of recipients. The server responded: Insufficient system storage.
sudo quota -u mydomain gives:
Disk quotas for user mydomain (uid 1364):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda2  242992  20485760 20485760           23018       0       0

sudo quota -u mailuser.mydomain gives:
Disk quotas for user mailuser.mydomain (uid 1365):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda2 3555016  10485760 10485760           13310       0       0

my main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mk3677070.ip-76-65-34.eu, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
allow_percent_hack = no
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
message_size_limit = 0
recipient_limit = 2000

I would appreciate any help!

Ensure that your mail server has enough disk space available. You can check disk space using the following command:
df -h

